# Angular4 exported member not recognised -- reasons for error message?

Tags: angular, typescript, import, module

I am creating a project for an absurdist drama collective and have so far created some code, and refactored it for routing.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <absurdist-drama></absurdist-drama>
  `
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'An Archipelago Grapefruit';
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule }       from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule }            from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }         from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }          from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule }        from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent }        from './app.component';
import { GrapefruitComponent } from './grapefruit.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    GrapefruitComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: 'absurdist-drama',
    component: GrapefruitComponent
  }
])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This seems like the app should work, and it's serving from localhost rather than on the server (though the computer is still connected to the internet), so I wouldn't have anticipated it being anything to do with security issues this time, yet I am getting the error:

```
src/app/app.module.ts (7,10): Module '"app/src/app/app.component"' has no exported member 'AppComponent'.
```

`app.component.ts` is in the same directory as `app.module.ts`. What could be the cause of the problem?

Comment: It didn't say the module was not found, it **said** there was no **exported** member called 'AppComponent'.

Comment: `export class AppComponent`

Comment: I restarted the server process and now the error has gone away (replaced by more comprehensible and actionable errors) so I guess it was just 'one of those things'...

Comment: @OmriLuzon that is definitely not related.